# Spliting a string for the first char only. Java

Tags: java, split

How can I split a string so that I only get the first letter, not an entire part word?

This is my current code and I'm using user input for the string. I'm creating an array of converted letters, adding them with each iteration of my for-loop. My code is a method for a Ceaser cipher.

```
    public String Encrypted() {  
            newString = getMessage();

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(messageArray));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(newString);
            testerString = new String[messageArray.length+1];

            for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
                String index1 = newString.substring(i);
                System.out.println(index1);
                String index2 = index1.toString();
                System.out.println(index2);
                int index3 = Arrays.asList(abc).lastIndexOf(index2);
                System.out.println(index3);
                testerString[i] = zyx[index3];

            }

        return Arrays.toString(testerString);
    }
```

Comment: a string is an array of characters, so you can use the index of 0 to get the first character of your array, or you could use Substring with a length of 1 to get it, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the first character of a String try: `thatstring.charAt(0);`

Also you can use `thatstring.substring(0, 1);`

Comment: Can you look at the answer again? This is not `substring()` it is `charAt()`. With `charAt()` you can get a character of the String at any index. (Starting at 0)

Comment: Oh, sorry and i just tried that too, but since I'm working with a string, BluJay is yelling at me that char can not be converted into  java.lang.string

Comment: `Character.toString(string.charAt(0));` what about this then?

Comment: String index out of range: 2
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

Comment: That is not part of the question, that is probably because you'r `for`-loop is incorrect.